# 'CollectingDispatcher' object has no attribute 'utter_response'

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I’am using http api and i want to return from action json response instead of text. I took a look documentation then found dispatcher utter_response. I tried to use it but i got errow below.

Error:

```
'CollectingDispatcher' object has no attribute 'utter_response'
```

my action class:

```
class ActionRoute(Action):
    def name(self):
        return 'action_route'

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):

        location = tracker.get_slot('location')
        travelmode = tracker.get_slot('travelmode')
        data = {
            "travelmode":travelmode,
            "location":location
        }
        response = "Hedef: {} ulaşım tercihi:{}".format(location,travelmode)
        dispatcher.utter_response(json.dumps(data))

        return [SlotSet("location", location),SlotSet("travelmode", travelmode)]
```

domain.md

```
actions:
 - utter_greet
 - action_route
 - utter_goodbye
entities:
 - location
 - travelmode
intents:
 - goodbye
 - greet
 - address
slots:
 location:
  type: text
 travelmode:
  type: text
templates:
 utter_goodbye:
  - text: Güle güle
  - text: Kendine iyi davran
  - text: Allaha emanet ol
 utter_greet:
  - text: Merhaba! Bugün nereye gitmek istersin?
  - text: Merhaba! Seni nereye götürüyüm?
 utter_default:
  - text: Seni tam anlamadım gideceğin yeri tekrar söyleyebilirmisin
  - text: Nasıl tam anlamadım. Bir daha söyler misin?
```

Comment: I solved it. I used utter_attachment instead utter_response. Maybe later you are experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

As per the official documentation of [rasa_core](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_core/blob/master/rasa_core/dispatcher.py), there is a method defined with name utter_response. In your case i guess you are importing Action from `rasa_sdk`.

if you are using:
`from rasa_core.actions.action import Action` then use: `dispatcher.utter_response(...)`
if you are using:
`from rasa_core_sdk import Action` then use: `dispatcher.utter_attachment(...)`

Comment: Yes I've realized now. But i got another error when i  use rasa_core.actions.action

Comment: i got No registered Action found for name 'action_route'

Comment: Thanks MVS. This should be accepted answer. Rasa lack of this note in their documents.